# Editing a color profile after calibration

Tags: display, color

Is there a way to edit a color profile once you have finished calibrating the screen? I have a Dell S2340L, and after calibrating, I've noticed there is too much red in the greys.

Am I able to adjust this without going through the whole calibration process again?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest tweaking the color balance on the monitor a bit. There should be a menu item to adjust color on the monitor itself. I suggest setting a custom color profile on the monitor rather then relying on the standard "warm"/"cool" type settings. (I have a Dell Ultra Sharp, and had to tweak this a few time before I got it right).

It's worth pointing out the calibration on most LCD/LED monitors can be very difficult since the color and contrast can change with the angle of view. While newer higher quality monitors minimize this, it's still evident.

Also if you really want everything well calibrated you can pick up a calibration system for ~$100. I have used a Huey Pro with great results for years, sadly it seems to no longer be sold, however this: http://www.pantone.com/pages/products/product.aspx?pid=1339&ca=2 seems to be similar (perhaps it's replacement).

Comment: just to confirm, as of July 2016, the Huey no longer works on OS X since 10.10. The Color Munki Smile has had no software updates in quite some time, but is still fully functional at OS X 10.11.5